# Why is ASP .Net displaying error messages and Login control in Spanish?

Tags: asp.net

Recently after working on a Globalization project I noticed that one of my ASP .Net websites started displaying error messages and the Login control in Spanish:

[image: Spanish error message]

[image]

It only happens on my local machine - not the production server.  Also I have tried multiple browsers.

How can I get these back to English?

Comment: Probably you have this somewhere for spanish language. Find it and comment it out or change it for English: System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture=System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

Comment: I have this in the Application_Start event:  CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling and re-installing .Net Framework fixed this issue.